# Python: Add calculated lines to a scatter plot with a nested categorical x-axis

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

Cross-post: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/add-calculated-horizontal-lines-corresponding-to-categories-on-the-x-axis/5544

I would like to duplicate this plot in Python:
[image: corrected Tableau plot]

Here is my attempt, using `pandas` and `bokeh`:

Imports:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, reset_output
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5, Turbo256
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.models import Band, Span, FactorRange, ColumnDataSource
```

Create data:

```py
fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears']
years = ['2015', '2016']

data = {'fruit' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1],
        '2016'   : [5, 3]}

fruit_df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("fruit")
tidy_df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
           .melt(id_vars=["fruit"], var_name="year")
           .assign(fruit_year=lambda df: list(zip(df['fruit'], df['year'])))
           .set_index('fruit_year'))
```

Create `bokeh` plot:

```py
p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(factors=tidy_df.index.unique()),
           plot_height=400,
           plot_width=400,
           tooltips=[('Fruit', '@fruit'), # first string is user-defined; second string must refer to a column
                     ('Year', '@year'),
                     ('Value', '@value')])

cds = ColumnDataSource(tidy_df)

index_cmap = factor_cmap("fruit", 
                         Spectral5[:2], 
                         factors=sorted(tidy_df["fruit"].unique())) # this is a reference back to the dataframe

p.circle(x='fruit_year', 
         y='value', 
         size=20,
         source=cds,
         fill_color=index_cmap,
         line_color=None,
        )
# how do I add a median just to one categorical section?
median = Span(location=tidy_df.loc[tidy_df["fruit"] == "Apples", "value"].median(), # median value for Apples
              #dimension='height', 
              line_color='red',
              line_dash='dashed', 
              line_width=1.0
             )

p.add_layout(median)

# how do I add this standard deviation(ish) band to just the Apples or Pears section?
band = Band(
    base='fruit_year',
    lower=2,
    upper=4,
    source=cds,
)

p.add_layout(band)

show(p)
```

Output:

[image: bokeh output]

Am I up against this issue? https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8592
Is there any other data visualization library for Python that can accomplish this? Altair, Holoviews, Matplotlib, Plotly... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Band` is a connected area, but your image of the desired output has two disconnected areas. Meaning, you actually need two bands. Take a look at the example here to better understand bands: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#bands

By using `Band(base='fruit_year', lower=2, upper=4, source=cds)` you ask Bokeh to plot a band where for each value of `fruit_year`, the lower coordinate will be 2 and the upper coordinate will be 4. Which is exactly what you see on your Bokeh plot.

A bit unrelated but still a mistake - notice how your X axis is different from what you wanted. You have to specify the major category first, so replace `list(zip(df['fruit'], df['year']))` with `list(zip(df['year'], df['fruit']))`.

Now, to the "how to" part. Since you need two separate bands, you cannot provide them with the same data source. The way to do it would be to have two extra data sources - one for each band. It ends up being something like this:

```py
for year, sd in [('2015', 0.3), ('2016', 0.5)]:
    b_df = (tidy_df[tidy_df['year'] == year]
            .drop(columns=['year', 'fruit'])
            .assign(lower=lambda df: df['value'].min() - sd,
                    upper=lambda df: df['value'].max() + sd)
            .drop(columns='value'))
    p.add_layout(Band(base='fruit_year', lower='lower', upper='upper',
                      source=ColumnDataSource(b_df)))
```

There are two issues left however. The first one is a trivial one - the automatic Y range (an instance of `DataRange1d` class by default) will not take the bands' heights into account. So the bands can easily go out of bounds and be cropped by the plot. The solution here is to use manual ranging that takes the SD values into account.

The second issue is that the width of band is limited to the X range factors, meaning that the circles will be partially outside of the band. This one is not that easy to fix. Usually a solution would be to use a `transform` to just shift the coordinates a bit at the edges. But since this is a categorical axis, we cannot do it. One possible solution here is to create a custom `Band` model that adds an offset:

```py
class MyBand(Band):
    # language=TypeScript
    __implementation__ = """
import {Band, BandView} from "models/annotations/band"

export class MyBandView extends BandView {
    protected _map_data(): void {
        super._map_data()
        const base_sx = this.model.dimension == 'height' ? this._lower_sx : this._lower_sy
        if (base_sx.length > 1) {
            const offset = (base_sx[1] - base_sx[0]) / 2
            base_sx[0] -= offset
            base_sx[base_sx.length - 1] += offset
        }
    }
}

export class MyBand extends Band {
    __view_type__: MyBandView

    static init_MyBand(): void {
        this.prototype.default_view = MyBandView
    }
}
    """
```

Just replace `Band` with `MyBand` in the code above and it should work. One caveat - you will need to have Node.js installed and the startup time will be longer for a second or two because the custom model code needs compilation. Another caveat - the custom model code knows about internals of BokehJS. Meaning, that while it's working with Bokeh 2.0.2 I can't guarantee that it will work with any other Bokeh version.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the Tableau plot; the ordering of categorical variables was incorrect(as you pointed out). The code to plot the std dev works; is there a similar way to add a median span per fruit?

Comment: I think this is the github issue I referenced: bokeh Spans can't reference a string, Spans may not also be the right approach, anyway, as they "extend to the edge of the plot area", which is not the behavior I want.

Comment: Looks like I should be using a `line` or `multi_line` approach, although the latter may also not work. I'll accept this one and make a new question regarding adding a median. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6907

Comment: Yes, you can just use `line` - there's nothing wrong with that. It's probably even more suitable. Same with the band - maybe a regular rectangle is more suitable.